# Compile a R-function inside c++ using rcpp

Tags: c++, r

I have a function in C++ which has, among others, a function as input-parameter:
f(int x,int y, Function f). I am using Rcpp to make it available in R, and pass a R function as a parameter.

Passing a R-function as parameter makes it go slower, and especially in a for-loop (because it has to call on the R-function in each iteration). I am wondering if it is possible to 'compile' the R-function once inside the c++ function, but before the actual for-loop? Then it doesn't need to evaluate it outside c++ in each iteration of the for-loop.

I am thinking along the lines of defining a function as a string in R and then get it compiled as a function inside c++. Then it would be actual c++-code? This way, if I made a shiny-app where the user could write his own function-definition as a string, it could get passed threw rcpp to c++ and the for-loop would not be slowed down.

Or, do anyone have a suggestion about how to get around this issue?

My goal is to have a for-loop in c++, for speed, which can use a function defined in R, for convenience.

Comment: Just by saying 'Rcpp' three times your R code does not become C++ code.

Comment: Hehe, I am aware of that. It would be neat if one could pass a function-definition as a string and then get it compiled as a function inside c++. Then it would be actual c++-code, or? This way, if I made a shiny-app where the user could write his own function-definition as a string, it could get passed threw rcpp to c++ and the for-loop would not be slowed down.

Comment: What would the benefit be over having the user just passing in a function actually written in Rcpp?

Comment: Simple example is as follows: Value of bank account A at time T based on returns from now and up to T and a costfunction C(...) - i.e. A(T, Return-vector, Costfunction(A(t<T,...), ...). The costfunction is one of the userinputs and dependent on A(t<T). I want to use c++ to speed up the for-loop, but still want to give the user the possibility to define a costfunction.